# Vectors components that are not contra or covariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that a vector can have contravariant and covariant components, but is it possible to have components that are neither contravarient or covariant? I suspect that the answer is yes, and that most of the time they are neither contravarient or covariant, but this is just a guess.

Comment: A vector is just an element of a vector space. Ideas like contravariance and covariance are artificial, extra datum attached to vectors that are relevant to applications, like physics.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the "components" of a vector then it is implicit that you are using a specific basis to express those components. Covariance and contravariance are labels (and a subscript/superscript notation) to indicate how the components are transformed with a change of basis.

Could a (non-zero) **vector** have components that are not affected by a change of basis ? Logically it would seem not, so that the answer is no.

If you extend the items under consideration to include scalars (as a "0 dimensional vector") then in various situations scalars are invariant (e.g. inner product) so that in that sense they are neither covariant nor contravariant.

You could also consider tensors which might have "mixed" aspects of covariance and contravariance.